# Opencart order view error

Tags: opencart

I installed Opencart 1.5.6 and set everything, template, vQmod bla bla bla..

I moved the same store to a different domain, everything works fine except this error.

`Fatal error: Call to a member function modCheck() on a non-object in   /home/blossomi/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 56`

After moving, when I click to VIEW an order it shows the above error. When I see those orders via Sales > orders > edit I can see and edit those.

Thanks for your time and help to fixing this.

Comment: You installed opencart to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vqmod installation is invalid. I would recommend you upgrade to the latest version that can be [downloaded from here](http://vqmod.com), as you are using an old one that requires an object instantiation

Comment: Thanks Jay, I updated vQmod but error is still there. My hosting server recently migrated and my website in /Home1/blossomi/public_html/vqmod/...... where to edit home to home1?

Comment: vQmod doesn't have any hard coded paths - it's based on OpenCart's. You will need to edit your OpenCart config.php and admin/config.php to reflect the change if you haven't already